# IPython uses a different $PATH environment than the shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, ipython, zsh

I had some problems with calling pip within the IPython REPL, and after a while I noticed that IPython doesn't use the same $PATH environment as my shell.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

$ ipython
In [1]: !echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/bin
```

It does seem to scramble the path order, and I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

I'm using ZSH installed through oh-my-zsh as shell, if it is of help.

This is what `sys.path()` returns:

```
['',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/bin',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sparsesvd-0.2.2-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/projects/pyresult',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/work/gavagai/userdata',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/work/gavagai/gavapi',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/runipy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/jimmy/.ipython']
```

And this is what `os.environ['PATH']` returns:

```
'/Users/jimmy/dev/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin'
```

Both seem to place it in the correct order.

Grateful for all help.

Comment: Could it be that `!` spawns a sub-shell that is different from the one you are normally using (like bash instead of zsh)?

Comment: @VolkerStampa I thought about that too, but the same thing happens in bash. The resulted IPython $PATH string isn't found in .bash_profile either.

Comment: What's `os.environ['PATH']` inside ipython? That checks what the Python process sees, rather than what the shell spawned by `!` sees.

Comment: @ThomasK Added the information as an edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `sys.path` has little to do with this; it's just the list of locations in which the Python interpreter can look when importing modules, and does not determine where executable programs are found by the shell. Some elements of the `PATH` are seen in that list, though, because the interpreter uses the path of its executable to build certain entries on `sys.path`.

`os.environ['PATH']` is, unsurprisingly, the same as the `$PATH` variable from the environment in which IPython is running. `!echo $PATH` prints out the `$PATH` variable from the subshell started by IPython to execute the shell escape (`!`).

One possible cause is that IPython is executing the shell commands using the OS standard shell which has not been tailored to set its path in the same way that your `zsh` has. You can confirm this by executing the IPython command `!echo $SHELL`. Since you confirmed this was not the case then the difference can be accounted for by the differences between a login shell and an interactive shell.

I don't know of a configuration item that will tell IPython to use another shell, but it's possible there is one. As a workaround, just make sure the other shell has a correctly configured path, or that interactive shells also see the environment you require.

See @mklement0's extremely authoritative answer for the whole, gory, messy details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but running !echo $SHELL actually returns the same string as running the command outside of IPython, that is, /bin/zsh.

Comment: In which case it's likely the difference between running a login shell vs. an interactive shell. [This document](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html) explains the difference well.

Comment: You are right; renaming my .zshrc file to .zshenv which runs for both interactive and login shells did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @JimmyC: I think you meant to say that `.zshenv` is sourced for both interactive _and non-interactive_ shells (i.e., scripts) - in other words: for _all_ (zsh) shells. `.zshrc`, by contrast, is sourced by _all interactive_ shells - whether login or not.

Comment: See this is why I didn't go into specifics in the answer. We should probably add a `zsh` tag if there is one. Done.

Answer (score 9):

To summarize and complement [@holdenweb's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24683986/45375), particularly with respect to OS X:

- **A subshell started from IPython with `!` is a *non-interactive* *non-login* instance of the user's *default* shell** - even if IPython was started from a *different* shell.

  - Behind the scenes, the subshell is started with `path/to/default/shell -c ...`
  - To see specifics, run `!ps -p $$ && :`

- `echo $SHELL` *always* tells you the *default* shell - even when run from a *different* shell.
- **Initialization files** sourced in **non-interactive non-login shells**:

  - `zsh:`: `/etc/zshenv` and `~/.zshenv`
  - `bash`: a script pointed to in the `$BASH_ENV` variable, if defined.

- As pointed out, shells load different/additional initialization files depending on whether:

  - the shell is a *login* shell or not
  - an *interactive* shell or not

  Note that a login shell can be interactive or not, and an interactive shell can be a login shell or not.

Thus, in the case at hand, potentially *two* additional initialization files were loaded in the *interactive* shell, explaining the difference in behavior between the interactive shell and the subshell created by IPython:

- `~/.zprofile` - if the shell is a *login* shell - which will be the case if `zsh` is the *default* shell (on OS X, all interactive instances of the default shell created in a terminal such as `Terminal.app` are login shells).
- `~/.zshrc`

---

Finally, on a related note, note that on OS X the default `$PATH` for NON-shell processes is:

```sh
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin  # Note the absence of /usr/local/bin.
```

and only *shells* add `/usr/local/bin` (by default; extensible) to that, via *system-wide* initialization files (that call `/usr/libexec/path_helper`):

- `zsh`:

  - `/etc/zshenv`
  - Note: takes effect for ALL `zsh` instances.
- `bash` (also when invoked as `sh`), `ksh`:

  - `/etc/profile`
  - Note: takes effect for LOGIN shells only.

Upshot:

- Non-shell apps see only the default `$PATH` (notably, without `/usr/local/bin` and other additions made via shell initialization files).
- `bash`/`sh` and `ksh` non-interactive non-login shells *not* launched from a login shell also see only the default `$PATH`. This happens, for instance, when GUI command-line launchers such as [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) create shell instances.
- `zsh` is *not* affected, because `/etc/zshenv` is read by *every* `zsh` instance.

Comment: Yes, nice answer